# FragmentManager gives me NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm checking fragments for the first time and I created a LinearLayout with a FrameLayout within and for my layout-sw600dp a LinearLayout with 2 FrameLayouts.

The one has an id of "main" and the other is "details".

The error I get is :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:395)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:385)
        at mes.fallstudio.tvfall.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
```

where line 28 is the last line here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private android.support.v4.app.Fragment mainFragment;
private android.app.Fragment detailsFragment;
private Boolean isDualPane = false;

private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main, mainFragment).commit();


}
}
```

XML layout files :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

this is for layout-sw600dp and the same without the 2nd FrameLayout ( details) for the xml file for the layout folder.

I'm extending AppCompatActivity if this helps.
Thanks you

Comment: Can you add your xml layout file?

Comment: @SvenDubbeld just did.

Comment: i don't really get why you add a fragment that is either already there, or null

Comment: also, you can't use v4 fragments and regular fragments together. this will be a problem at some point

Comment: @njzk2 what you mean by : either already there, or null ? Isn't this the way to add dynamically fragments based on the device ( tablet or mobile ) ?

Comment: Yes you are right about the regular fragments. I changed detailsFragment to a v4 fragment.

Comment: `mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main);` Either there is already a fragment, and adding it again is not very interesting, or there is not, and this returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` uses `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html

EDIT:

In your code you try to get `mainFragment` from the XML layout. However, you do not define it there. You can either instantiate `mainFragment` in your code:

```
mainFragment = new MainFragment();
```

Or define it in your XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="mes.fallstudio.tvfall.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

In the latter case you don't need to use the `FragmentManager` at all in your code unless you need to manipulate the fragments at run time.

In both cases you also need the actual fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```